# INSERT INTO with no SELECT throws: Error #1242: Subquery return more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to insert data into my Database but my query throws the error `#1242: Subquery returns more than one row`

**The table does get inserted 1 or 2 rows but then it throws this error.**

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO candidato (nombres, apellidos, nombrePuesto, ciudadOrigen, ubicacionPuesto, reubicacion, empleadoActual, certificaciones, disponibilidad, sueldoActual, nivelIngles, beneficiosActuales, observacionesGen, expectativaSalarial, experienciaGen, actitud, expectativasPuesto, añosExperiencia, solicitante, staffingPlan, cubreCapacidades, observacionesTec, tipoCandidato) 
VALUES ($nombres, $apellidos, $nombrePuesto, $ciudadOrigen, $ubicacionPuesto, $reubicacion, $empleadoActual, $certificaciones, $disponibilidad, $sueldoActual, $nivelIngles, $beneficiosActuales, $observacionesGen, $expectativaSalarial, $experienciaGen, $actitud, $expectativasPuesto, $añosExperiencia, $solicitante, $staffingPlan, $cubreCapacidades, $observacionesTec, $tipoCandidato);
```

I am also using a trigger that inserts data in another table when this one gets a new row inserted:

Here is the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER asignarNotificacionCandidatoPropuesto
AFTER INSERT ON CANDIDATO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @idSolicitud = (SELECT DISTINCT r.idSolicitud FROM REQUISICION AS r INNER JOIN STAFFING_PLAN AS s ON r.idRequisicion=s.requisicion INNER JOIN CANDIDATO AS c ON c.staffingPlan=NEW.staffingPlan);
    
    INSERT INTO NOTIFICACION(fechaHora, tipo, contenido)
    VALUES (NOW(), 'candidatoPropuesto', CONCAT("{", "'idCandidato' : '", NEW.idCandidato, "'}"));
    -- ", ", "'idSolicitud' : '", @idSolicitud,
    IF NEW.idCandidato IS NOT NULL THEN
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RECIBE(destinatario, notificacion)
    VALUES(NEW.solicitante, (SELECT MAX(idNotificacion) FROM NOTIFICACION));
    END;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Make sure that any of the variable defined in the `VALUES ( .. )` doesn't return more than 1 row. Otherwise, you need to rethink your `INSERT` approach.

Comment: The query you're assigning to `@idSolicitud` is returning more than one row. You need to figure out how to correct the query to return just the ID you want.

Comment: @FanoFN A variable can't hold more than 1 row.

Comment: Unrelated to the error: You should use the `JSON_OBJECT()` function to create JSON, not string concatenation.

Comment: Ahh.. noted @Barmar. I was testing that theory just now and I can't figure out how to assign a variable with more than 1 row - which is funny because I am aware of that.